# Flowable: How to enable history cleaning in flowable for more than one tenant

Tags: spring-boot, flowable

I am using flowable 6.5.0
I am trying to use Shared Engine/Multi Schema process engine configuration based on this link: https://blog.flowable.org/2018/09/11/multitenancy-in-flowable/

If I have more than one tenant, how the history configuration will work?
I tried to do this:

```
MultiSchemaMultiTenantProcessEngineConfiguration config
        = (MultiSchemaMultiTenantProcessEngineConfiguration)processEngine.getProcessEngineConfiguration();
config.setEnableHistoryCleaning(true);
config.setHistoryCleaningTimeCycleConfig("0 30 * * * ?");
config.setCleanInstancesEndedAfterNumberOfDays(Integer.valueOf(1));
```

But the ACT_RU_TIMER_JOB table is empty after starting the server.
Not sure where flowable stores the details about the history timer configuration?

Also, the above configuration will be applied for all the tenants?
Is it possible to have different history cleaning setting for different tables?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.